# Python zero-size array to ufunc.reduce without identity

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a histogram of some data that is being stored in an ndarray. The histogram is part of a set of analysis which I've made into a class in a python program. The part of the code that isn't working is below.

```
def histogram(self, iters):
    samples = T.MCMC(iters) #Returns an [iters,3,4] ndarray
    histAC = plt.figure(self.ip) #plt is matplotlib's pyplot
    self.ip+=1 #defined at the beginning of the class to start at 0
    for l in range(0,4):
        h = histAC.add_subplot(2,(iters+1)/2,l+1)
        for i in range(0,0.5*self.chan_num):
            intAvg = mean(samples[:,i,l])
            print intAvg
            for k in range(0,iters):
                samples[k,i,l]=samples[k,i,l]-intAvg
            print "Samples is ",samples
            h.hist(samples,bins=5000,range=[-6e-9,6e-9],histtype='step')     
            h.legend(loc='upper right')
            h.set_title("AC Pulse Integral Histograms: "+str(l))
    figname = 'ACHistograms.png'
    figpath = 'plot'+str(self.ip)
    print "Finished!"
    #plt.savefig(figpath + figname, format = 'png')
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
File "johnmcmc.py", line 257, in histogram
  h.hist(samples,bins=5000,range=[-6e-9,6e-9],histtype='step') #removed label=apdlabel      
File "/x/tsfit/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7238, in hist
  ymin = np.amin(m[m!=0]) # filter out the 0 height bins
File "/x/tsfit/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1829, in amin
  return amin(axis, out)
ValueError: zero-size array to ufunc.reduce without identity
```

The only search results I've found have been multiple copies of the same two conversations, from which the only thing I learned was that python histograms don't like getting fed empty arrays, which is why I added the print statement right above the line that's giving me trouble to  make sure the array isn't empty.

Has anyone else come across this error before?

Comment: do numpy histograms handle 3D data OK?  What happens if you pass `np.ravel(samples)` or `samples.flat()` to `h.hist`?

Comment: That's the error you'd get if none of the values fell into the range `[-6e-9, 6e-9]`, but since I don't know the units I don't know if those are unusually small values or not.  Are you sure they all do?  (I'm also not sure I understand what you're doing with samples, but that's another question.)

Comment: @DSM , that solves it. Tinkered with the range a bit and it worked. Thanks a lot!